# Didn't Adam make us all sinners?

Tags: romans

[Romans 5:18-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%205%3A18-19&version=NLT) (*NLT translation*):

> ¹⁸ Yes, Adam’s one sin brings **condemnation for everyone**, but Christ’s one act of righteousness brings a right relationship with God and new life for everyone. ¹⁹ Because one person disobeyed God, **many became sinners**. But because one other person obeyed God, many will be made righteous.

Why didn't Paul write "all became sinners"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Greek word πολλοί (*polloi*) translated as "many" in [Rom 5:19](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/romans/5-19.htm) should not be interpreted as "less than all", but is another way of saying "all humanity" or "the multitudes".  The word choice may be influenced by Paul's possible allusion to the justification of the "many" in [Isa 53:11-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isa+53%3A11-12&version=ESV) (*ESV*):

> ¹¹ Out of the anguish of his soul he shall see and be satisfied;
> by his knowledge shall the righteous one, my servant,
> make many to be accounted righteous,
> and he shall bear their iniquities.
> ¹² Therefore I will divide him a portion with the many,
> and he shall divide the spoil with the strong,
> because he poured out his soul to death
> and was numbered with the transgressors;
> yet he bore the sin of many,
> and makes intercession for the transgressors.

[New Covenant Commentary on Romans](https://www.logos.com/product/38322/romans) by Craig S. Keener said that “The many” in this context refers to all who are defined by their relationship to either Adam or Christ.:

> The phrase refers to the elect at Qumran (1QS 6.6–21; cf. Dan 12:3; Marcus 1956), but is here used also for the “many” in Adam (5:19a), parallel with “all humanity” (5:18); the phrase can refer to “the multitudes” (e.g., Epictetus Disc. 1.2.18; 1.3.4; 2.1.22). It is not impossible that Paul alludes to the justification of the “many” in Isa 53:11–12 (though “many” is frequent in the LXX).

Comment: How does this answer the question about guilt which you never mention?

Comment: @Dottard The OP seems to focus the question **only** on the contrast between "everyone" in v. 18 and "many" in v. 19.  Until the OP modifies / comment on the question to ask about our own guilt vs. inherited guilt, I think my answer is sufficient.  One potential issue I came across is well explained in [this article](https://defendinginerrancy.com/bible-solutions/Romans_5.19.php).

Comment: While this is a very good answer - it does not actually address the question of how we inherit Adam's guilt or not.

Comment: I suggested an edit removing the code formatting, we should avoid using code blocks for plain text since it messes up screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

The "many" is in contrast to "one" - the emphasis is that the actions of one can affect many. Using "all" here would detract from the point.

He already made the point in verse 18 that Adam brought condemnation for everyone. The point of verse 19 is that the actions of one person can affect others, and that just as Adam's actions can make other people sinners, so Christ's actions can make other people righteous.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers to this question which depends on whether one answers from a Catholic or Protestant perspective.  I will attempt to give what the Scriptures actually say.

**1.  Sinners for what we have **DONE** and what we **ARE****

Note the instruction in 1 John 1:8, 10 -

> **8** If we say we have no sin [Noun], we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us.
>
> **10** If we say we have not sinned [Verb], we make Him out to be a liar, and His word is not in us.

Note that here sin is both a noun and a verb; that is, we are sinners because of what we are and because of what we have done.  The fact that we are sinners before we even did anything is also expressed in Ps 51:5 -

> Surely I was sinful at birth, sinful from the time my mother conceived
> me.

David is saying that we all have sinful tendencies and enjoy what we should not (see also Paul's discussion in Rom 7).  According to Rom 3:23 - we have all sinned (done something wrong) as well.

**2.  Who is Guilty?**

Note that while we are all sinners at birth before we did anything wrong, we are still innocent of committing sin (but it usually does not take long!).  However, we do not inherit Adam's sin as guilt because this is a firm law in the Torah:

> Deut 24:16 - Parents are not to be put to death for their children,
> nor children put to death for their parents; each will die for their
> own sin.

See also Eze 18:20.  Thus, whatever we inherit from Adam it is not his guilt for we had no part in that guilt.

**3.  What we inherited**

The condemnation we inherited from Adam is the sinful tendencies not the guilt.  That is, we inherited a fallen human nature that is naturally attracted to sin.

The word translated "condemnation" in Rom 5:18 is κατάκριμα (katakrima) which only occurs three times in the NT and all in the book of Romans, namely, Rom 5:16, 18, 8:1.  Note the extended passage in Rom 5:16-19 -

> 16 The gift is not like that which came through the one who sinned;
> for on the one hand the judgment arose from one offense, resulting in
> condemnation, but on the other hand the gracious gift arose from many
> offenses, resulting in justification.
>
> 17 For if by the offense of the one, death reigned through the one,
> much more will those who receive the abundance of grace and of the
> gift of righteousness reign in life through the One, Jesus Christ.
>
> 18 So then, as through one offense [o]the result was condemnation to
> all mankind, so also through one act of righteousness [p]the result
> was justification of life to all mankind.
>
> 19 For as through the one man’s disobedience the many were made
> sinners, so also through the obedience of the One the many will be
> made righteous.

Paul is contrasting the sinful nature of man inherited from Adam with the righteousness of the second (perfect) "Adam" namely Jesus Christ.

He concludes this lengthy discussion in Rom 8:1-3 by using the same word:

> Therefore there is now no condemnation at all for those who are in
> Christ Jesus. For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus has
> set you free from the law of sin and of death. For what the Law could
> not do, weak as it was through the flesh, God did: sending His own Son
> in the likeness of sinful flesh and as an offering for sin, He
> condemned sin in the flesh,

**CONCLUSION**

We do not inherit guilt from Adam but do inherit sinful flesh (= human nature) from Adam.  However, being a sinner by nature (as opposed to action) makes just as much a sinner as by action and in need of salvation.  This is one of the distinguishing features of Jesus - he was perfect in all senses and was untainted by sin (Heb 7:26), did not have a sinful nature and thus, did not need a savior Himself.

**Back to Romans 5:15-19**

This passage in Rom 5 has a repeated structure contrasting the first and second Adam as follows:

| Rom 5 ref | First Adam | Second Adam = Jesus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| V12 | Sin passed to ALL men | Sin reigned until Jesus |
| V15 | MANY (= all) died (compare Rom 3:23) | Grace abounds to MANY (= all) |
| V16 | One sin brought condemnation | The gift brings followed many trespasses brought justification |
| V17 | One man's trespass death reigned | Those who receive grace, righteousness reins in the life |
| V18 | One trespass brought condemnation for All men |  |
| V19 | Disobendience of one man the many (= all Rom 3:23) were made sinners | Obedience of one man the many (= all, Rom 3:24) wil be made righteous |

This is confirmed by similar teaching elsewhere:

- Rom 11:32, For God has consigned everyone to disobedience so that He may have mercy on everyone.
- 2 Cor 5:14, For Christ’s love compels us, because we are convinced that One died for all, therefore all died.
- 2 Peter 3:9, The Lord is not slow in keeping His promise as some understand slowness, but is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish but everyone to come to repentance.

Comment: v18 "the result was condemnation to all mankind"... sounds like *guilt* to me. Rather than simply the fallen nature you suggest. and v19 we are made sinners. This denotes  guilty as!

Comment: @user48152 - that is OK - if you believe we must confess Adam's sin to be forgiven of his sin because we are guilty of his sin that is up to you.

Comment: This is not bad as an interpretation of Rm 5:12-19, but it doesn't explain the core of the question: why "many" and not "all"?

Comment: @Pavel - I believe the "many" (v15) does mean "all" - V12 & 18 says, "all', see also Rom 11:32 and 2 Cor 5:14, Rom 3:23, 24, 2 Peter 3:9, etc.

Comment: Expand this comment and edit it in your answer and it will make it really answer what the OP really asked.

Comment: @Dottard How do you explain infant mortality if babies are not guilty already?  Sure they are NOT guilty of specific sins in their mothers womb & at a young age(Rom 9:11), but what of infant death?  Do babies inherit a sinful nature but die because of natural causes?  Aren’t the wages of sin death? (Rom 6:23).  Aren’t natural causes, deformities, cancer, miscarriages, etc, all because of Adam’s sin?

Comment: @Cork88 - I fully agree.  All death is a result, ultimately of sin whether our own or someone else's.  All children are born with a sinful nature before they have committed any sin.  That is my point above.

Comment: @Dottard When you said then: "We do not inherit guilt from Adam but do inherit sinful flesh (= human nature) from Adam."  How do we not inherit guilt from Adam if babies still die?  Humans with their will resisting God ultimately are guilty because of volition (Rom 1:18-3:20) but Babies, if they are NOT guilty, why do they pay the wage of sin via death?  If Adam merely gave them a corrupt nature by which actual transgressions progress, then shouldn't babies not die upon entrance of the world if they are free from the guilt?  Wouldn't guilt imply death by extension?  Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @Cork88 - I think I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.  All I can say we suffer the consequences of both our own and others' actions.  If an innocent person is murdered by a murderous criminal, the person suffers the consequences of the murderer's sin.

Answer (score 0):

Dottard, one thing that can help you with "babies still die" is with the scripture; "Therefore, just as through one man(Adam)sin entered the world, and death through sin, and thus death spread to all men, because all sinned—" Romans 5:12. That's right, "spread to all men" means all descendants of Adam. But, the good news (the Gospel) is; "For if, by the trespass of the one man, death reigned through that one man, how much more will those who receive an abundance of grace and of the gift of righteousness reign in life through the one man, Jesus Christ!" Romans 5:17. Remember Christ said to Mary; "I am the resurrection, and the life: he that believes in me, though he were dead, yet shall he live:" John 11:25. Sure, babies cant believe, but Jesus made provision for them saying; "Allow little children to come unto me, and forbid them not: for of such is the kingdom of God." Luke 18:16.

Comment: Also, the chart above is very helpful explaining Romans 5, yet verse 16 is not understandable to me. It say;s; "The gift brings followed many trespasses brought justification". I would like to get another interpretation for clarity. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).